# How to use flash in Nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use the `flash` notification to show a successful message. I tried it as I mention below. When I tried the below code it doesn't show anything. How can I solve this?

page.js :

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
     req.flash('error_messages_test', 'Invalid credentials');
     res.redirect('/page');
  } catch (e) {
     //code...
  }
};
```

page.handlerbars :

```
<div>
  {{#if error_messages_test}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_messages_test}}</div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

app.js :

```
const flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing "error_messages_test" var to your view from route /page?

Comment: @R.K.Saini Actually I am not sure It. How Can I check it

Comment: Check your route /page and from there pass your "error_messages_test" variable to view like this  res.render('page', { error_messages_test: req.flash('error_messages_test') });

Comment: @R.K.Saini Nope. I have not done such a thing. How can I plug into my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the "error_messages_test" variable to your view from the function that handles your "/page" route.

Try like this:

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res){
  // other stuff
  // Get flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
  res.render('page', { error_messages_test: req.flash('error_messages_test') });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the the "error_messages_test" as a middleware so you can use it on every route.

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
     res.locals.error_messages_test = req.flash("error_messages_test");
});
```